# How to bind just one field from object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to bind just one field from an object, how can I do it, I try to add Child object to find method but where I find the child I got errors because child just have pesel without first name and Lastname, here is my POJO class and controller

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Imie nie może być puste")
    private String firstname;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Nazwisko nie może być puste")
    private String lastname;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11,message = "Pesel musi mieć 11 znaków")
    private String pesel;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "campId")
    private Camp camp;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

controller:

```
@PostMapping("/find")
    public String find(@Valid String pesel, BindingResult result, Model model) {
            if (childService.checkExist(pesel)) {
                Child childByPesel = childRepository.findChildByPesel(pesel);
                model.addAttribute("childbypesel", childByPesel);
                return "findSuccess";
            }else
                return "findError";
    }
```

find.html

```
<body class="text-center">
<div th:insert="header"></div>
<form th:action="@{/find}" method="post" th:object="${childbypesel}">
    <div>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pesel')}" th:errors="*{pesel}" class="validation-message"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="pesel">
    <input type="text" name="pesel" th:field="*{pesel}" placeholder="pesel">
    </div>
    <input id="findbypesel" type="submit" value="Sprawdź" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
</form>
<div th:insert="footer"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean under "binding a field".

Comment: I want verify that user write right value in pesel field, pesel field should have 11 characters, when user will write less or more than 11 characters,he shouldn't be redirect to "findSuccess" just should see information "pesel should have 11 characters" Here is my html page with using thymeleaf: